# Inferring a pipelined divider in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, synthesis

I want to synthesize an integer divider in Verilog to divide 16-bit integers by 8-bit integers. I assume that the compiler will be way more clever than me when it comes to implementing the details of the logic, so I want to give it a `/` sign and just let it be creative. I don't want an insane amount of logic with a huge propagation delay, so I'll obviously have it pipelined. I want to tell the compiler "you have X clock cycles in which to deliver me a result".

I suspect that this is possible because there's precedence for this in FPGA toolchains when it comes to inferring hardened, pipelined multiply blocks from constructs that look similar to what I have below ([Xilinx example](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/8657.html), [Yosys example](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/issues/882))

I have 2 questions that I'd like answers to:

- Is the below enough to tell most Verilog compilers to generate a multi-cycle divider with whatever method it wants?
- What's a pretty sane number of pipeline stages to offer the compiler? I'd think it would be the number of bits in the denominator (8 in my case).

```vhdl
`timescale 1ns/100ps

module pipelined_divider (input                                    clock,
                          input signed [width_numerator - 1 : 0]   numerator, 
                          input signed [width_denominator - 1 : 0] denominator,
                          output signed [width_numerator - 1 : 0]  quotient);

    parameter width_numerator = 16, width_denominator = 8, depth = 8;

    reg signed [width_numerator - 1 : 0] pipeline [(depth - 1) : 0];
    integer i;

    assign quotient = pipeline[depth - 1];

    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        pipeline[0] <= numerator / denominator;

        for (i = 1; i < depth; i = i + 1)
          pipeline [i] <= pipeline [i - 1];
    end
endmodule
```

For reference, I'm aiming at a Lattice iCE40 FPGA at the end of this. The model I'm looking at has 5,280 logic elements, and they look like this:
[image]

I realize that the right answer here is probably "just try it and find out", however, when you google similar questions for programming languages and not HDLs, there are tons of answers about how to drop hints to a compiler to get it to do something smart. I wish there were more easily google-able discussions like that when it came to hardware synthesis, so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Most likely not. It'll probably be an unpipelined divide followed by a long chain of registers.

Comment: There's some precedent for this sort of thing when it comes to hardened multipliers. I've updated my question with examples.

Comment: Try it with and without the pipeline, and compare the achievable clock speed. Also examine the synth tool settings/options/preferences/advanced settings (they hide settings all over the place) for automatic pipeline register settings or "pipeline balance" etc.

Comment: @BrianDrummond You're probably right... I need to buckle down and do it and will post results here later.

Comment: You'd think that this would be a common feature, but I've only seen retiming work well in expensive flavors of Synplify. DSP inference is a little different since that's just recognizing a chunk of logic that can be taken over; retiming requires synthesis to partition logic on its own.